# hibernate JPA unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-jpa

I am writing a spring boot + Hibernate JPA  application and i  my hibernate code is not working in that below are the details

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserBean {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idUser")
    String id;

    @Column(name = "UserName")
    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Service/DAO:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class SpringBootService {

    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public boolean userLogin(UserBean bean) {

        String hql = "FROM UserBean WHERE id = ? ";
        int count = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, bean.getId())
                .getResultList().size();
        return count > 0 ? true : false;
    }

}
```

and below is my table

[image]

I am getting the below exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'userbean0_.id_user' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
```

I have checked the table name and the column names in the entity class all of then are correct and this is a simple mapping i am not involving second table as well.

Comment: I see your IdUser column is int whereas its defined as String in model class.

Comment: Will that be a problem ? that works in hibernate xml configaration.

Comment: i have changed it to integer and tried and i am getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
String hql = "FROM UserBean WHERE id = ?1 ";
    int count = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(1, bean.getId())
            .getResultList().size();
```

EntityClass:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserBean {

@Id
@Column(name = "idUser")
String id;

@Column(name = "UserName")
String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: You declare primary key as string. Remove Generated value to get string type id.

Comment: i have updated that as integer and i also tried by removing generator it did not work getting the same error

Comment: i used above enity class. its work for me. give ur stacktrace

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'userbean0_.id_user' in 'field list'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_162]

Comment: pls check my given entiry class & ur class and  "id = ?1 ". don't miss 1 after '?'.

Comment: I tried by putting "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create" it has overridden my old table and deleted all the data in that table and it is working now

Comment: issue was it was taking the primary key as id_user (not sure why)

Answer (score 0):

The UserBean model is not entity object. So you cannot use this statement for execute

Comment: i have declared entity annotation for the class